# Brute force attack

Tags: cryptography

In Microsoft- CHAP (Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol), the message block is divided into three blocks and each having 7 bytes and all block are encrypted using three different keys.

Now the brute force attack combination required is

2^56 + 2^56 + 2^56

out of the three blocks the original content is of only 16 bytes (divided in to 7,7 and 2) and remaining 5 bytes are padded to bring the third 7 bytes block size .

Hence they have given the brute force attack combination required is

2^56 + 2^56 + 2^16 approximately equal to 2^57.

I would like to know how the 2^16 and 2^57 comes.

Also they have given Attackers do not need 2^192 effort only 2^56 + 2^56 + 2^16 approximately equal to 2^57 is required.

It is available in the "www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/CS265/projects/Spr05/ppt/MS-CHAP.ppt‎"

Can any one help me in this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography in general (crypto.stackexchange.com) and not about programming per se.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of unclear what you're asking for, but I'll try to help out.

2^16 comes from the 16 bytes "the original content" you mention at near the top of your post.

2^57 is approximately 2^56 + 2^56 + 2^16, as you said, so that's where it comes from.

Comment: How the additive complexity of 2^56 + 2^56 + 2^56 =a total keyspace of 2^ 57.59? How to derive this?